# How to reverse action on sibling element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a menu bar with sub menu using Jquery. There are two item with sub menu. When i click on once i want it slide down and when i click second one then second one need to slide down but first one or all another one need to slide up. I tried following:

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-lang">
    <ul>
        <li class="lang">
            <a href="">ENG <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
            <a href="">USD <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">USD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VND</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
        .footer-lang ul{
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
        }
        .footer-lang .lang{
         display: inline-block;
        }
        .footer-lang .lang a{
         display: block;
         padding: 8px;
         color: #000;
        }
        .footer-lang .lang > ul{
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
        }
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.footer-lang .lang a').on('click', function(e) {

      $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('slow');
      e.preventDefault();

     });
    });
```

Comment: I like a short Solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On click make other submenu to `slideUp` `fast` or `slow` and than toggle see below snippet for more info

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.footer-lang .lang a').on('click', function(e) {
      $(".lang > ul").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('slow');
      e.preventDefault();

     });
    });
```

```css
.footer-lang ul{
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
        }
        .footer-lang .lang{
         display: inline-block;
        }
        .footer-lang .lang a{
         display: block;
         padding: 8px;
         color: #000;
        }
        .footer-lang .lang > ul{
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-lang">
    <ul>
        <li class="lang">
            <a href="">ENG <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lang">
            <a href="">USD <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">USD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VND</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

one method is to add a class signifying open when clicking it and then close that class before opening another item.  something like this would use that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.footer-lang .lang a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // close the open
  $('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').slideToggle('slow);

  // open the closed
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('slow');
  $(this).addClass('is-open');
 });
});
```